# Node.js slow mySQL querys

Tags: mysql, node.js

I need to insert a lot of data into a table (about 50 querys a second) and this is the table structure is use.

```
CREATE TABLE `word` (
  `title` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `company` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `known` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `appearances` smallint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `word`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`title`,`company`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `word` (`company`,`title`),
```

And here are a few example queries

```
INSERT INTO `word` (`title`, `company`, `known`) VALUES('retrogaming', 2, 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `appearances` = `appearances` + 1

INSERT INTO `word` (`title`, `company`, `known`) VALUES('gamedev', 2, 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `appearances` = `appearances` + 1

INSERT INTO `word` (`title`, `company`, `known`) VALUES('retrogamer', 2, 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `appearances` = `appearances` + 1
```

I figure the queries execute to slow since after 5 seconds I've executed 332 queries and only returned successfully 125 What could be a way I could speed this process up?

When I execute one of these queries manually it takes about 0.01760 seconds, which is quite slow considering how much I need to execute. I understand this table would be relatively slow because of the double key, but I didn't expect it to be this much. `title` and `company` are supposed to form a unique key together.

**EDIT:**

This is the code I use in node in order to insert

```
const con1 = mysql.createConnection(require('../mysql1.json'));
con1.connect();

function analyzeWords(tweet, array, company) {
  let splitTweet = tweet.split(` `);

  for (let i = 0; i < splitTweet.length; i ++) {
   let word = splitTweet[i];
     let index = inArray(word, knownWords);
    if (index) {
      submitWord(word, 1, company);
    } else {
      submitWord(word, 0, company);
    }
  }
}

function submitWord(word, known, company) {
  if (word.length <= 55) {
    let sql = `INSERT INTO \`word\` (\`title\`, \`company\`, \`known\`) VALUES('${word}', ${company}, ${known}) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE \`appearances\` = \`appearances\` + 1`;

    con1.query(sql, (error, results) => { if(error) console.log(error) });
  }
}
```

Every sentence gets passed into the `analyzeWords()` so I can keep track of the word usage for every 'company'

Comment: 0.01760 seconds to run an insert query with an on duplicate statement...How much faster do you want it to run? That's pretty fast already.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your node.js code.

Comment: InnoDB table engine write every INSERT directly to a disk cause alot of random disk i/o.. starting a transaction would most likely speed it up..

Comment: @SamM to me this sounds slow, unless the table is already really large. Just a feeling though.

Comment: @SamM how would I go about storing this information in a faster format, I will store the title column with inside another table and then use keys instead of words. I suppose this would speed it up but what else could I do?

Comment: @Evert its 24008 rows, so I don't know your definition of large :p

Comment: @SamM I've now included the code

Comment: @RaymondNijland I see, how would I go about this? As far as I can see I should start with `BEGIN WORK` run my other queries i mentioned before and then `COMMIT` but this does not improve speed. So I think I misunderstood something

Comment: @Schotsl that's very tiny to me. Should be super fast. I would at that point stop looking at MySQL and take a look at what might be wrong with your operating system/hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I moved my MySQL server tot digital ocean ssd based droplets and it's able to keep up perfectly now, the query takes 0.0012 seconds